# Changing collation on a column with multipage rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

We're in the process of changing the collation of our database.

We've run into a problem, when I try to alter one of the columns (with the datatype varchar(max)) I get the following error:

```
Cannot create a row of size 8083 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.
```

If I check the size of the biggest post.

```
select top 1 LEN(Document) as l1,* from GroupDocument where LEN(document) > 8000 order by LEN(document) desc
```

I get the size 39431 which would be approx 10 pages.

I assume that this is the problem why I cant change the collation. I havent run into this problem earlier with the other columns. Any help would be appreciated.

I guess one solution would be to copy all the content of the table to another table, change collation and then move it back again. But I'd rather not do that if it's possbile.

EDIT:

Tried the following:

create table temptable (id int, document nvarchar(max))

insert into temptable (id, document) select GroupDocumentID, Document from GroupDocument

alter table GroupDocument drop column Document
alter table temptable alter column document nvarchar(max)
ALTER TABLE [GroupDocument] add [Document] ntext  COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS NULL

update GroupDocument set Document = (select temptable.document from temptable where temptable.id = GroupDocument.GroupDocumentID)

Still the same problem.

The row that is causing the problem has a varchar that is 7996 bytes, that + some ints makes it a boundary case I guess.

Comment: You are not really understanding the issue. `row size` isn't the lenght of the string on one column (and, for the record, it can be a lot longer with `VARCHAR(MAX)`), its the actual size on bytes of the whole row, that includes every column on your table

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. The thing is. That varchar(max) seems to be in the same row if the total size < 8060, but for a special case the total size is just under 8060, so when I try to change the collation, one extra column is added. And then it overflows. =(

I'm not able to build a temporary table with the info, drop the column and then copy it. Same problem unfortunately.

Comment: In this case the table has this layout; "int, int, nvarchar(max), datetime, bit, int, int". I can't see any reason for the row size to exceed 8060 bytes unless it's trying to store the data in the column instead of off-row.

Jonas has also tried forcing the use of off-row storage for large value types using "sp_tableoption 'Document', 'large value types out of row', 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a combination of forcing larger values to be out of row.

EXEC sp_tableoption 'dbo.GroupDocument', 
    'large value types out of row', 1

Cleaning the table.

dbcc cleantable('ExamDoc', 'groupdocument', 0)

and finally dropping and rebuilding the indexes for the table.

Solved the problem! :D